# How to prevent holes that makes the displacement modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I made a displacement texture and it looks fine, but when I apply it with the displacement modifier, there are this hole outlines that is surrounding every object.[image]
How to prevent the modifier from making those holes?

This is the texture - 
[image]

Comment: I know that baking the objects with another plane object undernith will probably solve the problem, but is there another way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "holes".. Where are the holes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Displacement Modifier, you can change the strength to a negative value.

[image]

EDIT:
You'll get what you are looking for if you modify the image that you're using to drive the displacement so that the value for the plane in isn't gray, but black.

Think of it this way: Black becomes the lowest point in the displacement and white the highest.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that does solve the problem, but then the model gets too flat, but thanks anyway

Comment: See the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your talking about the chunky borders along all of the displaced elements?

This is the trouble with using the displace modifier for this sort of thing.  Where I you, the first thing I would do is ask myself "Do I really need the displace modifier?"  The trouble is: you have to add so much geometry in order to get good results.  Also, the higher resolution the image the better the results.  Looking at the attached image I can see that the edges in your image are far to low resolution to get good results.

So the next step would be to look at using bump/normal maps or displacement on the material level to fake the results your after.

If this isn't good enough and you really need to have geometry, your probably better off to model this shape as a mesh. I guarantee you'll end up with a lower poly count.

If you try all of this and you still determine that you have to use the displace modifier to accomplish your goal, then I recommend you go back to the graphics program you used to make the image and reproduce it at 4K or greater.  Get ready for a long render time though.

Comment: The least thing that I need for this model is the displacement modifier. I asked of curiosity, why the displacement modifier does that, but I solved the problem. Good advises, thanks.