# How to add a ground for a model that is used as a displacement modifier?

Tags: modifiers

How would anybody go if you have a model and you use it as a displacement texture, but the ground to be separated from the model (not literaly separated, but to distinguish the ground from the model)? Maybe the boolean can solve the problem, but of big curiosity, what are some of the ways and approaches of doing that?

I'm aiming for this kind of result - [image]

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are asking.. What do you mean by "if you have a model and you use it as a displacement texture"? What do you mean by ground?

Comment: What I mean is - If you bake a displacement texture of the model on a plain and then add a displace modifier to the plain and then when you apply a material on it, I don't want the hole plain to be with that texture, just the formation that forms from the displacement modifier witch is the yellow thing show on the image above.

Comment: The formation and the parts that are supposed to act as a ground don't have to be on a same mesh.

Comment: Oh.. I see now, partially. Though how do you want the displacement to be separated from the plane? Also, do you have any particular reason you want to use a displacement? Why not put a plane under (or through) the existing model?

Comment: I thought of that too, but the material will still be visible underneath. thanks anyway

Comment: What do you mean? (sorry.. I just don't understand :/)

Comment: Ok, it's like this - To achieve a result like the image above, its just that the model to be just a plane that has a Displace modifier on it and the parts that pop up from the displacement texture to act as a model (something like the glossy object on the image) and the parts that are standing still to act as black texture like in the image above.

Sorry if I confused you again

Comment: Basicaly, the displacement modifier to be in a desired shape on witch I can add a material and the ground to be a separete material.

Comment: The ground to be a different mesh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15015/discussion-between-gandalf3-and-vladimir).

Comment: Sorry, I can't log in for some reason on chat. 
The model to be the displace modifier and the ground to be a separate material that is outlining it.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you are saying. I still think it would be better to use the existing model + a plane though.. What do you mean by "the material will still be visible underneath"?

Comment: You said to add another plane slightly above the uneffected parts of the model that has the Displace modifier and use it as a separete material so that the parts that are effected from the modifier will be above that plane. And that is a good idea if I understood you, but the rest of the mesh with the Displace modifier will still be visible underneath that plane.

Comment: Much like the answer of "Cegaton". Any other ideas?

Comment: I was thinking of using the original mesh, and not using a displace modifier at all. Here's [an example file I made](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29730).

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking more in terms of the possibilities in Blender with the Displace modifier.

Comment: Okay. I still don't see how using a displace modifier has any advantage in this case though..

Comment: Ok, imagine this scenario - You have a model with no modifiers on it, but however the model is still to high poly. You make displacement textures from the model on a plane. Then add a low amount of Multiresolution modifier and a Displace modifier on it. Duplicate the plane. Make the amount of the multiresolution much higher. Apply both of the modifiers on both planes. Bake a normal map form the higher poly plane on the lower poly plane. And then separate the ground from the formation that was caused by the modifiers (something like the answer of Cegaton. I find this combination pretty handy.

Comment: Basically, to use a Displace modifier in a combination with normal map and alpha texture. It's not who knows what, but its handy in many situations.

Comment: Well, whatever works for you.. Though it seems to me that the displaced plane is higher poly than the original in this case..

Comment: If you mean "in this case" for what I asked in the first place on this post, then I agree, the Displace modifier is a pretty bad choice for this model, but since I'm not that experienced with Blender, who knows, maybe it has some advantages.

Comment: Or maybe you mean the displacement texture I posted on the previews question is baked as a higher poly model then what it is on the render I posted here. No, they are the same polygon count

Comment: You had it the [first time](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/how-to-add-a-ground-for-a-model-that-is-used-as-a-displacement-modifier?noredirect=1#comment17444_12119) :)

I meant that using the model in your render as is is probably going to use fewer polys than baking it to a displacement map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use an image to control the displacement:
[image]

[image]

Generate an image that controls an alpha channel for texturing

[image]

Use that image to combine different materials:

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks. Any video links on how to generate an alpha texture/map?

Comment: bytheway - The materials are on a same mesh or separete?

Comment: For the displacement texture I just used your the image you posted and replaced the gray background with black in photoshop. . To create the alpha I selected the background, inverted the selection (to select everything but the background) and filled it with white.

Comment: Just one plane mesh is used.

Comment: Which image were you using as a the starting point for the displacement texture? Not the "I'm aiming for this kind of result..." one?

Comment: The base image used was from the OP previous question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12116/how-to-prevent-holes-that-makes-the-displacement-modifier

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but I used the one you made an alpha texture from it.

Comment: Yeah, The image above (the very first one) was the model I used for the displacement texture, if that's what you are asking. Which then you made an alpha map of it.

Comment: I think what @ajwood is asking is how you generated the original displacement map image.

Comment: I placed a plane above the model and baked the model on it. And I'm not sure, but maybe I placed another plane a little underneath the model to prevent that spiky outline which I asked in this post - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12116/how-to-prevent-holes-that-makes-the-displacement-modifier