# How to make a bannister for a spiral staircase?

Tags: modifiers

Let's say you have a shape that would act as one stair step:

[image]

Then you add an empty and both the object and the empty have the same origin point. Then you add an array modifier to the stair step, and manipulate the empty to make a spiral staircase.

[image]

How would anybody make a railing surrounding the staircase?

[image]

When subdivision surface is used, the fence not to be straight from step to step, but round.
Here is what I mean:
Not this - [image]

But this - [image]

Edit: The merge option in the array modifier doesn't seem to do a good job
[image]
[image]
Does anybody knows how can I make a fence that follows the spiral in a perfect alignment with the spiral that follow the stairs and at the same time every part of it to be connected so that when subdivision surface is added to it, the fence to be rounded, like the representation in the 5th image from above?

Edit: I did it as Gandalf3 explained, but I'm having a problem.
[image]

What is that line that is visible when subdivision surface is added and how to fix it?
Note: I was having trouble with vertex groups so I duplicated the model and on the duplicate I applied the array so I could use it as a guide to align the vertecies of the end of the cylindar to the begining of the second one ("cursor to selected"-"selection to cursor"). And I edded a hook modifier and made the "Object" to be the "Empty" and on "Vertex groups" I added the vertex group. And I'm not sure if they are now connected. And I didn't parent the empty to the other empty. But they should be connected now right? Here is the blend file if someone would like to check it out -

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29776

Its my first upload file so inform me if it can't opened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to just add some cylinders to your stair object:

[image]

1. Add the cylinder meshes while in edit mode with the stair object selected.
2. Line up the geometry on the end of each cylinder (snapping is useful here, as it leaves no doubt about which vertex should be merged with what):

   [image]

   What I did in the gif:

   1. Note the Z rotation of the array empty (this is only needed for the initial setup, it will be done automatically later), then enter edit mode and rotate the end to the cylinder the same amount (in my case, ~`3.1`)
   2. Enable *apply modifier to edit cage* on the array modifier (inverted triangle icon).
   3. Ensure the snapping type is set to *Vertex* and *Self snapping* is enabled in *3D view > Header*.
   4. Select any part of the horizontal cylinder, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (select linked) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> (Invert selection) <kbd>H</kbd> (Hide selection) to get a clearer view and make snapping easier.
   5. With the rotated end of the horizontal cylinder selected, press <kbd>G</kbd> and then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with your mouse cursor over the other end of the cylinder in the next array element.
3. Now enable *Merge* in the array modifier to merge those vertices together, resulting in a sub-serfable railing:

   [image]
4. By using hooks parented to the main empty, you can keep the merged parts in the right locations, no matter where you move the main empty:

   [image]

   To do this, select the end of the horizontal railing cylinder and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>*> Hook to new object*. This will automatically add a vertex group, an empty, and a [hook modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Hooks). The hook modifier will bind the location of the vertices in the vertex group to the location of the empty.
5. Parent the newly created hook empty to the empty controlling the array (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>*> Object*).

   [image]
6. Repeat the hook+parent for the bottom edge loop of the central column.

See this [**example .blend**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29758) to explore it yourself :)

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that, what ever the fence is made of, I want it to fit the spiral shape using the empty. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vladimir If you add the cylinders to your stair object while in edit mode, so that they are both part of the the object with the array modifier (as shown in the image), it will follow the empty automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I see that now, but the height of the horizontal cylinders would have to be adjusted manually so it doesn't follow the spiral shape of the stairs perfectly. And the horizontal like cylinders have only one cylinder to connect to so if you add a "subdivision surface" modifier it will not be a smooth/round shape. The horizontal cylinders would still be straight horizontally. Any other ideas?

Comment: If my last comment was confusing, I edited my question, check it out.

Comment: I like your last explanation, but Is there a way to make a curve to follow the spiral formation made by the empty resulting in a fence?

Comment: Gandalf3, I tried your approach, but some funny distortion of the mesh happens and when it merges, only some vertices merge. No matter how I play with the merge value, I can't get even close to your result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Vladimir Can you upload your .blend or some screenshots?

Comment: The subdivision surface modifier is added after the array.

Comment: @Vladimir Your vertices aren't very aligned.. (I'll update my answer)

Comment: Ok. I never used merging for the array modifier very often, because I always like clean and fixed results, but I'll try to handle it. Thanks.

Comment: I just saw your blend file in your answer and figured out that you were using a "hook" modifier (that I never used before) so, the empty should be at the center of the end of the horizontal cylinder right? Why are there two Hook modifiers? Does the "force" control the merge limit?

Comment: @Vladimir I'm updating my answer, hopefully it will be clear in a second..

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bother, but how did you parent the empty 001 to just the handle since its not a separate object from the stairs?

Comment: @Vladimir It is a separate object. It's not possible to have an empty which is part of any other object (even another empty).

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand something. When I select the object, everything highlights yellow. When I tab into edit mode, everything is editable at the same time, like one object. There is no other object. And how did you parent the empty 001 to the fence? I know how to make parent, but this is just on one part of the cylinder. How? Sorry, I just don't get it.

Comment: @Vladimir I'm not sure what you mean entirely.. The empty isn't parented to the fence/railing, it's parented to the empty controlling the array. If that doesn't answer your question, could you upload your .blend?

Comment: It is about your blend file. You said the fence is a separate object, but there is only one object in your file. However the "empty 001" is controlling one side of the cylinder and the other remains stationary. How is that achieved?

Comment: @Vladimir I meant the empty is a separate object. The empty is the target of a hook modifier, which basically parents a *vertex group* to an object (in this case, an empty). So there is a vertex group of one side of the cylinder, which is hooked to `empty.001`.

Comment: Ok. I'm really a sort of nub in blender so, now its clear

Comment: Guys, try to use the chat.

Comment: @DantheMan Yeah.. Sorry. [Vladimir said he couldn't log on](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/how-to-add-a-ground-for-a-model-that-is-used-as-a-displacement-modifier/12122#comment17406_12119) though.. :/

Comment: I'm sure I typed the correct name and password, but it says repetetly "no account found with that name", so I'll try not to type a lot in the "comments" (if that's some kind of violation or something).