# How to make bas-relief from picture

Tags: modeling

I want to replicate a bas-relief like this coin and was wondering if I can do this without sculpting.
[image]

Also, I want to make each letter and face relief rounded, not just simply extruded.

Comment: You can use a displacement modifier. Have a look to the documentation https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html. And an example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12116/how-to-prevent-holes-that-makes-the-displacement-modifier

Comment: The answer by lemon is correct, and just wanted to remind that you need to have enough subdivision to get it to look right. If you get it working well enough, you might consider baking to a normal map and using that for a lower poly version if you need multiples in scene.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I know the displace modifier, but that worked for me with HI-RES height map greyscale pictures (the simple greyscales weren't too good).

Comment: Have you tried to use 'filter size' in the 'image sampling' section (that will smooth/interpolated this small definition image)?